# a class method returns the same value all the time

Tags: java, methods

My code is given below. the problem is that whatever value (0 or 1) I enter in player[xxx].takenSquare[row][col]=true;  (where the xxx is ) the method does not set it correctly and as a result the `drawSquare` method always returns " O " even if the player 1 has taken the square..

```
static boolean  [][]takenSquare= new boolean [3][3];
int [][]playerTable; //gia tin niki
static tictac[] player = { 
    new tictac( "PlayerName1" ),
    new tictac( "PlayerName2" ),
};
static private int row;  //<---
static private  int col;  //""
private  static int activePlayer;
public tictac(String name){
    this.name=name;
    playerTable=new int[3][3];

}
public static boolean isValidMove(int row,int col){
    boolean valid=false;
    if( ( row >= 0 && row<3 ) && ( col >=0 &&col < 3 ) ) {

        if ( takenSquare[ row ][ col ] == false ) {
            valid = true;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}   //isValidmove
public static void setMove (int nrow, int ncol,int active){
    col=ncol-1;
    row=nrow-1;
   /* StringTokenizer tokenizer=new StringTokenizer(move);
    this.row= Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
    this.col= Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()); */
  if (isValidMove(row,col)){
        player[xxx].takenSquare[row][col]=true;
        player[xxx].playerTable[row][col]=table[row][col];
    }

}
public static String drawTable(){
    if ( ( row >= 0 && row<3 ) && ( col >=0 &&col < 3 ) ){
    String a="";
    a+=(drawSquare(0,0)+"|");
    a+=(drawSquare(0,1)+"|");
    a+=(drawSquare(0,2)+'\n');
    a+=("-----------")+'\n';
    a+=drawSquare(1,0)+"|";
    a+=drawSquare(1,1)+"|";
    a+=(drawSquare(1,2)+'\n');
    a+=("-----------")+'\n';
    a+=drawSquare(2,0)+"|";
    a+=drawSquare(2,1)+"|";
    a+=(drawSquare(2,2));

    return a;
    } else return "error";

}

public static String drawSquare(int x,int y){
    if (player[0].isTaken(x,y)) {
        return " O ";
    }   else if (player[1].isTaken(x,y)) return " X ";
    else return "   ";  

}
public boolean isTaken(int x,int y) {
    return takenSquare[x][y];
}
```

Comment: yes.. it s a tic tac toe game (wannabe :P).. .can you help me .. :/

Comment: Can you post the entire class definition ? and what is player[xxx]. I do not see xxx defined anywhere

Comment: Your code appears to have a lot of unnecessary [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity). If you simplified by re-writing it from a top-down approach, it will be much easier for you and us to understand and debug.

Comment: help me to fix it guys please

Comment: It would be easier if you had a single grid to represent the game. You could populate each cell with a'*' to represent an unused cell, or an X/Y or whatever to represent each of the players turns. You could write a test to prove a new game had 9 unused cells. Then write a test to enable a player to pick a cell, a test to check if a cell is unused, and keep building till you have a game

Comment: @Romski nice idea !! but what about the winning term? ..i want a table for each player how should this work?

Comment: "winning term"? This does not explain why you want a "table for each player". Usually a game has a table, and each player interacts with that single same table.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels can you briefly explain how can i make the winning algorithm?

Comment: The check for win should be done in the Game class, not the Player class. After each move, check any row, diagonal or column associated with the position of the last placed piece, see if all are X or O, and declare winner.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so i should make two classes one for the game in which will be the game table, the game winning check, and another class for the players in which will be what ? the moves for each player in each step ?

Comment: I would make it model reality a bit. You will have 1 Game object that controls the game, and it encapsulates the game board and the rules of the game, and a Player object that interacts with the game. Player requests of Game to make a move, and Game decides if its valid or not, if a win has been achieved, whose turn it is, etc...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels do i have to extend Player class in Game class?

Comment: No. You only use inheritance when a true "is-a" relationship exists. If you have an Animal class, a Dog and a Cat class can inherit from it, since they are sub-types of animals, but is Player a sub-type of Game or is a Game a sub-type of a Player? No. So inheritance should not be used in this situation.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so  for example in the main program i have p1.setMove , in the player class i have the setMove method which calls  a game.moveRequest(p1,row,col) and in the game method i have the method static void moveRequest(new player p1,int row , int col); ???

Answer (score 0):

*player[0].takenSquare[row][col]* is the same as *player[1].takenSquare[row][col]* and the same as *ClassName.takenSquare[row][col]* where 'player' are objects of class ClassName. 

The way you reference a static field is allowed, but it is not what you intend to do with it!
 Both of your players share that resource, that's why it will be the same for whatever player!
 Please redo your code, and make sure that you don't use static for non-shared resources to avoid this problem.